# Android Crash SQLite Unable to Replicate

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an Android App published in which I updated to a new version adding a SQLite database.  All of my testing seems to work fine.  However, since I've had about 300 users update since release in past 2 days, I have had 9 users reports the exact same crash.

The error comes on the very first call to the SQLite database.  So my first thought is that the SQLite database create and initial insert statements are not complete prior to that first call.

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.janzen.bodybuildingdiet/com.janzen.bodybuildingdiet.DietActivity}:    
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while   
compiling: UPDATE DAYMEAL SET DAY_INT=
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): ,    
while compiling: UPDATE DAYMEAL SET DAY_INT=
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at   
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:923)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:534)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:65)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1370)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1309)
at com.janzen.bodybuildingdiet.StatusData.updateFieldDayMeal(StatusData.java:1083)
at com.janzen.bodybuildingdiet.DietActivity.setupInitialDay(DietActivity.java:124)
at com.janzen.bodybuildingdiet.DietActivity.onCreate(DietActivity.java:103)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
```

Here is the method for UPDATE DAYMEAL where the error happens, however I do not think this method's code is the problem as it works well in other parts of the App)

```
    public void updateFieldDayMeal(String updateArray[]) {
    open();
    String fieldToUpdate = updateArray[0];
    String valueToUpdate = updateArray[1];
    String query = "UPDATE DAYMEAL SET " + fieldToUpdate + "="
            + valueToUpdate;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    c.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Here is my onCreate (in my Main Activity for the App) and setupInitialDay method which makes the call to the SQLite class:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_diet);

    statusData = new StatusData(getBaseContext());
    setupButtons();
    setupProgressBar();
    setupInitialDay();
    setupValues();

    firstTime();
    populateDietList();
    registerClickCallback();

    Appirater.appLaunched(this);

}

private void setupInitialDay(){

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    Date d = new Date();
    String dayOfTheWeek = mic.dayWeekNumber(sdf.format(d));

    String [] updateArray = new String[] { "day_int", dayOfTheWeek };
    statusData.updateFieldDayMeal(updateArray);
}

public String dayWeekNumber (String day) {
    String dayNum = "";
    if (day.equals("Sunday")) {
        dayNum = "7";
    } else if (day.equals("Tuesday")) {
        dayNum = "2";
    } else if (day.equals("Wednesday")) {
        dayNum = "3";
    } else if (day.equals("Thursday")) {
        dayNum = "4";
    } else if (day.equals("Friday")) {
        dayNum = "5";
    } else if (day.equals("Saturday")) {
        dayNum = "6";
    } else if (day.equals("Monday") {
        dayNum = "1";
    }
    return dayNum;
}
```

Comment: Show the `dayWeekNumber` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the weekday into a string with `SimpleDateFormat` and then converting back into a number by comparing this string will not work if you use English day names on a non-English device.

Instead of using strings, create a [Calendar object](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html); then use `get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`, then convert than number to your own number.

Comment: Thank you for answer.  I'm not sure why my question received a -1.  I think it was very legit and led to a useful issue of the SimpleDateFormat method.

Answer (score -1):

Instead use `execSQL` to update -

```
public void updateFieldDayMeal(String updateArray[]) {
    open();
    String fieldToUpdate = updateArray[0];
    String valueToUpdate = updateArray[1];
    String query = "UPDATE DAYMEAL SET " + fieldToUpdate + "="
            + valueToUpdate;

    db.execSQL(query);

    db.close();
}
```

Comment: This makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @CL. - I am using `execSQL` to update any table data and it is working without issues. If it is the same thing then pardon me. Just a little clue for the OP if works. :)